# How to display HTML <FORM> as inline element?

Tags: html, css

This is probably a basic html/css question...

I have a simple one-button form that I would like to display inline inside paragraph text.

```
<p>Read this sentence 
     <form style='display:inline;'>
     <input style='display:inline;' 
            type='submit' 
            value='or push this button'/>
     </form>.
</p>
```

Even though form has style=display:inline attribute, I get a linebreak before the form. Is there a way to get rid of it?

Can form elements appear inside `<p>`?

Comment: Thanks all for the answers and comments!

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Move your form tag just outside the paragraph and set margins / padding to zero:

```
<form style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
  <p>
    Read this sentence 
    <input style="display: inline;" type="submit" value="or push this button" />
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Margin and padding in my form did not work for me, I had to use display:inline instead and then margin/padding was not necessary.

Comment: display:inline did it for me too.  Why not add that to the form style in your answer.

Answer (score 58):

`<form>` cannot go inside `<p>`, no. The browser is going to abruptly close your `<p>` element when it hits the opening `<form>` tag as it tries to handle what it thinks is an unclosed paragraph element:

```
<p>Read this sentence 
 </p><form style='display:inline;'>
```

Answer (score 23):

You can try this code:

```
<form action="#" method="get" id="login" style=" display:inline!important;">

  <label for='User'>User:</label> 
  <input type='text' name='User' id='User'>

  <label for='password'>Password:</label><input type='password' name='password' id='password'>
  <input type="submit" name="log" id="log" class="botton" value="Login" />

</form>
```

The important thing to note is the css style property in the `<form>` tag.

`display:inline!important;`

Answer (score 6):

According to [HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/sgml/dtd.html#block) both `<form>` and `<p>` are block elements and you cannot nest them. Maybe replacing the `<p>` with `<span>` would work for you?

EDIT:
Sorry. I was to quick in my wording. The `<p>` element doesn't allow any block content within - as specified by [HTML spec for paragraphs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#edef-P).

Comment: Some block elements can be nested (like div elements) but some are special and should not be nested. The paragraph tag, for example, can only contain inline elements.

Answer (score 2):

Add a inline wrapper.

```
<div style='display:flex'>
<form>
 <p>Read this sentence</p>
 <input type='submit' value='or push this button' />
</form>
<div>
    <p>Message here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: you didnt close the first div

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish what you want, I think, simply by including the submit button within the paragraph:

```
     <pre>
     <p>Read this sentence  <input  type='submit' value='or push this button'/></p>
     </pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the style `float: left` in this way:

```
<p style="float: left"> Lorem Ipsum </p> 
<form style="float: left">
   <input  type='submit'/>
</form>
<p style="float: left"> Lorem Ipsum </p>
```

Comment: It is better to fix the markup as suggested in other answers than do `float` tricks.