# How to make link with POST and without new line

Tags: javascript, html, href

I try to generate some square matrix, and need to send data in post method, I found solution with javascript and form, but all time new form create new line. Othervise I move opening form block out of iteration but it make just 1 variable when i presed on any number, it send always 1 in "place" field.

```
<%
        for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) { %>

            <form name="submitForm" method="POST" action="buy">
            <%
                for (int j = 1; j <= 20; j++) {%>
                    <a href="javascript:;" onclick="parentNode.submit();"> <%=j%> </a>
                    <input type="hidden" name="row" value="<%=i%>"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="place" value="<%=j%>"/>
                    <% if (j == 20) { %>
                        <p>
                    <%}%>
                <%}%>
            </form>
        <%}
%>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CSS to make sure the form displays as an inline element, not a block element which has a line-break before and after it.

```
<style>form { display: inline }</style>
```

or

```
<form name="submitForm" method="POST" action="buy" style="display:inline">
```

Some pitfalls are discussed in [How to display HTML <FORM> as inline element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106720/how-to-display-html-form-as-inline-element) since the open `<form>` tag still implies the end of a paragraph element that otherwise appears to contain it.

Comment: <style>form { display: inline }</style>
It is work perfect. I just can't accept your message now, need to wait 7 min

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand the question but I am sure you can not make link with POST metod, to do that you need to use the GET metod

Comment: The link is only used for its default styling and its `onsubmit` handler causes the form to be posted instead.

Comment: ok, my bad, I am not good enough in javascript to help :( sorry