# How to display html elements beside each other

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following code inside my asp.net MVC Razor view:

```
<p>
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.GroupID)
    @Html.Partial("_CreateOrEdit", Model)

    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary"/>
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "SecurityGroup", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <input type='submit' value='Cancel' class='btn' />
}
</p>
```

How I can force the two `<input />` elements to be displayed beside each other, instead of being under each other?

Comment: If the answer works, can you please select it?

Answer (score 2):

[How to display HTML <FORM> as inline element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106720/how-to-display-html-form-as-inline-element)

A `<p>` element is only allowed to contain inline elements. `<form>` isn't inline, it's a block element. Try wrapping the forms in `<div>`s for example:

```
<div class="form-container">
    @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.GroupID)
    @Html.Partial("_CreateOrEdit", Model)

     <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary"/>
    }
</div>
<div class="form-container">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "SecurityGroup", FormMethod.Get))
    {
        <input type='submit' value='Cancel' class='btn' />
    }
</div>
```

Then use the following stylesheet (either as inline style or in a CSS)

```
.form-container{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: it will work ,, but there will be wasted space between the two button.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to this paragraph (or ID).
Make this class (ID) to be displayed inline.

```
p.inlineParagraph{
    display:inline;
}
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/nnTht/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a table to place the buttons next to each other:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.GroupID)
        @Html.Partial("_CreateOrEdit", Model)
        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary"/>
      }
    </td>
    <td>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "SecurityGroup", FormMethod.Get)) {
          <input type='submit' value='Cancel' class='btn' />
        }
    </td>
</tr>
```

You can also check out the [bootstrap navigation bar and div tags](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar).