# Field positioning in mvc

Tags: css, razor, html-helper

I am trying to position these text fields next to each other and have them in the following format:

```
(______) _____ - _____
```

My main problem is getting them to be next to each other. Does anybody have any suggestions on what I should do?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
<label style="margin: 5px" id="lblPhoneNumber">Phone Number (optional)</label>
<p>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Pharmacy.PhoneNumber)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Pharmacy.AreaCode, new { style="width:3em", maxlength=3}) 
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Pharmacy.PhoneNumberFirstThree, new { style="width:3em", maxlength = 3 })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Pharmacy.PhoneNumberLastFour, new { style="width:4em", maxlength = 4 })
</p>
```

Comment: Use style= "display:inline-block ; float:left;" in css

Comment: put the textboxes in a div and then you can apply the display and float attributes

Comment: By default the display attribute has "block" value which means they are staked one over the other

Comment: Also refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17592369/how-to-display-html-elements-beside-each-other post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be something like. You need to do it for all three textboxes:

```
@Html.TextBox("Something", @Model.text, new {style = "display: inline-block;float:left"})
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you. :)