# Django - Incorrect form error display

Tags: python, django, forms

When I try to display form error fields I get very strange behaviour:
[image]

I have tried almost every combinations of my code and can't understand what am I doing wrong. How does one display errors on the form?

I have such setup:

base.html:

```
<head>
    ...
</head>
<body>
<header>
    {% if user.is_anonymous %}
        <div class="welcome">
            <span>Welcome!</span>
        </div>
    {% else %}
        <div class="wrapper">
            <a href="/">Home</a>
            <a href="/users/">Public Profiles</a>
            <a href="/users/{{ username }}">My Profile</a>
            <a href="/ribbits">Public Ribbits</a>

            <form action="/logout">
                <input type="submit" id="btnLogOut" value="Log Out">
            </form>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
</header>
<div id="content">
    <div class="wrapper">
        {% block flash %}
            {% if auth_form.non_field_errors or user_form.non_field_errors or ribbit_form.errors %}
                <div class="flash error">
                    {{ auth_form.non_field_errors }}
                    {{ user_form.non_field_errors }}
                    {{ ribbit_form.content.errors }}
                </div>
            {% endif %}
            {% if notice %}
                <div class="flash notice">
                    {{ notice }}
                </div>
            {% endif %}
        {% endblock %}
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

register.html:
    {% extends "base.html" %}

```
{% block content %}
    <div class="panel right">
        <h1>New to Ribbit?</h1>
        <p>
        <form action="/signup" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
            {% for field in user_form %}
                {{ field }}
            {% endfor %}
            <input type="submit" value="Create Account">
        </form>
        </p>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Form:

```
class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True, widget=forms.widgets.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Email'}))
    first_name = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.widgets.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'First Name'}))
    last_name = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.widgets.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Last Name'}))
    username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.widgets.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Username'}))
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.widgets.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password'}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.widgets.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password Confirmation'}))

    def is_valid(self):
        form = super(UserCreateForm, self).is_valid()
        for f, error in self.errors.iteritems():
            if f != '__all_':
                self.fields[f].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'error', 'value': strip_tags(error)})
        return form

    class Meta:
        fields = ['email', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password1',
                  'password2']
        model = User
```

view:

```
def signup(request):
    user_form = UserCreateForm(data=request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if user_form.is_valid():
            username = user_form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = user_form.cleaned_data['password2']
            user_form.save()
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('/')
    return register(request, user_form=user_form)


def register(request, user_form=None):
    form = user_form or UserCreateForm()
    return render(request, 'register.html', {'user_form': form})
```

Comment: You've got javascript handling the submission of the form?

Comment: Note you've missed out the final underscore in `__all_`.

Answer (score 1):

The Django docs for [rendering forms manually](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually) cover how to display errors.

You are getting strange behaviour because you are doing very strange things by overriding `is_valid()` method.

It isn't working because `error` is an `ErrorList` instance, not a string. When you do `strip_tags(error)`, it isn't stripping the tags as you expect.

In effect, you are substituting

```
<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul>
```

into

```
<input value="<value goes here>" />
```

The result is

```
<input value="<ul class=" errorlist">
<li>This field is required.</li></ul>
" />
```

Which looks very strange when displayed by your browser.

If you really want to display the errors as the forms values, you'll need to conver the `ErrorList` to a string. Instead of trying `strip_tags(errors)` (note error**s** because there can be more than one), you can get a list of the error strings with

```
[error for error in errors]
```

Comment: I'm playing with code from here: https://github.com/gnarula/django-ribbit, all i try to do is to move signup form to personal page from home. Why they got it working then?

Comment: It looks like `strip_tags(error)` behaved differently for Django < 1.5. The ribbit example website must be running an older version of Django.

Comment: What would be the hot-fix?

Comment: All I want is wrong fields to be highlighted for example with red color, as they are in their example.

Comment: I've already suggested that you can get a list of the strings with `[error for error in errors]`. You can then turn that list into a string `", ".join(...)`. However, the code looks very fragile, it would be much better to render the form in a more conventional way.

Answer (score 0):

In your `register.html` you have a `<form>` inside of a `<p>` tag. That's against the rules as some people have explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106720/how-to-display-html-form-as-inline-element). Try putting the `<p>` inside the form instead.

The behavior your seeing might be your browser attempting to close that first `<p>` tag.

Comment: Actually the answer from @Alasdair better explains your problem, but you should still fix that `<p>` tag :P

Comment: It didn't help, but I removed `<p>` anyway.