# how to place my two buttons in html side by side

Tags: html, css, forms

I am working on my HTML file. I have a table which contains four actuators. And these actuators have two buttons which are ON and OFF. How do I place the ON and OFF buttons side by side per actuator so that it will not look dull with its spacing per button?

Here's my code:

```html
<FORM>
    
    <table width='100%'>
    <tr align='center'><td>
    <div style='border:2px solid; border-radius:30px;padding: 30px;width:400px;background-color:#F4F4F4;'>
    
    </FORM>
    <center><font size="5" color="#1717C9" face="Arial"><B>MANUAL CONTROL</B></font>
    <font face="Arial" size="3">
    <form action="" method="POST" name="form">
    <p class="title"> WATER PUMP </p>
    <p class="form">
    <input type="submit" id="on" value="ON">
    <input type="hidden" name="ctl" value="1">
    </form></p>
    
    <form action="" method="POST" name="form">
    <p class="lol">
    <input type="submit" id="off" value="OFF">
    <input type="hidden" name="ctl" value="0">
    </form>
    </p></font>
```

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: I see some mistakes in your code. try to insert on and off inputs in only one form tag. then you can style it with display: inline-block;

Comment: @AminAdel It depends on the functionality, if its two different form actions, the best way is to handle it in the action. If its otherwise, we need to have a work around right?

Comment: in these situations I always use buttons and jQuery event handler. it's very easy, if you are interested I can write that as answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here
Browsers automatically add some space (margin) before and after each `<p>` element. The margins can be modified with CSS (with the margin properties).
According to HTML spec both `<form>` and `<p>` are block elements and you cannot nest them. Maybe replacing the `<p>` with `<span>` would work for you.

```html
<FORM>

<table width='100%'>
<tr align='center'><td>
<div style='border:2px solid; border-radius:30px;padding: 30px;width:400px;background-color:#F4F4F4;'>

</FORM>
<center><font size="5" color="#1717C9" face="Arial"><B>MANUAL CONTROL</B></font>
<font face="Arial" size="3">
<!-- Style display inline for forms and remove paragraph between them and reorder hidden name ctl -->
<form action="" method="POST" name="form" style="display: inline;">
<p class="title"> WATER PUMP </p>

<input type="hidden" name="ctl" value="1">
<input type="submit" id="on" value="ON">
</form>

<form action="" method="POST" name="form" style="display: inline;">

<input type="submit" id="off" value="OFF">
<input type="hidden" name="ctl" value="0">
</form>
</p></font>
```

Comment: Hi Keerthana, you seem to be copy-pasting a lot of content from the Internet to your answers without mentioning the source. This answer has content from https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_p.asp and http://stackoverflow.com/a/1106761. While it's usually ok to reference other content and answers, you **must** mention that you didn't write the text yourself. Otherwise it's considered plagiarism and often also a copyright violation. Thank you!

Comment: @AllenDelaCruz, if KeerthanaPrabhakaran solution worked, please kindly mark his answer as so, so he can get the deserved points and that the rest of the community knows that your question has been answered and addressed :) Thanks!

Comment: Basically, I wanted to make the point clear for the one who asked question. The answer, as far the code is concerned, is not copy pasted. I'll make sure I'll quote the reference here on. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```html
   
    
    <table width='100%'>
    <tr align='center'><td>
    <div style='border:2px solid; border-radius:30px;padding: 30px;width:400px;background-color:#F4F4F4;'>
    
    
    <center><font size="5" color="#1717C9" face="Arial"><B>MANUAL CONTROL</B></font>
    <font face="Arial" size="3">
    <form action="" method="POST" name="form">
    <p class="title"> WATER PUMP </p>
    <p class="form">
    <input type="submit" id="on" value="ON">
    <input type="hidden" name="ctl" value="1">

    <input type="submit" id="off" value="OFF">
    <input type="hidden" name="ctl" value="0">
    </p>
    </form>
```

UPDATE:

```css
form{display:inline}
```

```html
<FORM>
    
    <table width='100%'>
    <tr align='center'><td>
    <div style='border:2px solid; border-radius:30px;padding: 30px;width:400px;background-color:#F4F4F4;'>
    
  
    <center><font size="5" color="#1717C9" face="Arial"><B>MANUAL CONTROL</B></font>
    <font face="Arial" size="3">
    <form action="" method="POST" name="form">
    <p class="title"> WATER PUMP </p>

   
   
    <input type="submit" id="on" value="ON">
    <input type="hidden" name="ctl" value="1">

    </form>
    
    <form action="" method="POST" name="form">

    <input type="submit" id="off" value="OFF">

</form></font></center>
```

Comment: if the two form elements have different functionalities (different actions, may be may be not, depends on the requirement), then on doing the way you've suggested wouldn't help right..

Comment: Hi! I already tried this but it did not work. I think there must be separate form tag for each of the button

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit the markup a bit. You can use `text-align: center` or even `display: inline-block` but first I've tided up the HTML and CSS.

```css
.box {
  border: 2px solid #000; 
  border-radius:30px;
  padding: 30px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width:400px;
  background-color:#F4F4F4;
  font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.title {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #1717C9;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
}
.text {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

form {
  text-align: center;
 }
```

```html
<div class="box">

  <p class="title">
      Manual Control
  </p>

  <form action="" method="POST" name="form">
  
    <p class="text">
      Water Pump
    </p>
    
    <input type="submit" id="on" value="ON">
    <input type="hidden" name="ctl" value="1">

    <input type="submit" id="off" value="OFF">
    <input type="hidden" name="ctl" value="0">

  </form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:flex;`

```
.form{
display:flex;
}
```