# How to use CSS to align HTML inline form correctly?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a template for blank filling, using HTML inline element forms display for which I found [this other answer very useful.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106720/how-to-display-html-form-as-inline-element)

My main challenge is that I would like the form to be horizontally centered and 50% of the screen width in the computer, 100% in a smaller screen device.

Vertically, I would like my text area to be aligned with the text.

I recently learned a bit of flex so I tried using it for the parent element (form) to align both vertically and horizontally but I have not managed to achieve the desired results. What am I missing here?

[image]

*index.html*

```
<body>
        <form style="margin: 0; padding: 0; display: flex; align-items: center; width: 50%; justify-content: center;">
            <p ><!--style="display: flex; align-items: center;">-->
              My name is 
              <textarea name="name" id="" cols="10" rows="1" placeholder="enter name"></textarea>
              and I come from a village called
              <textarea name="village" cols="10" rows="1" placeholder="enter village"></textarea>
                . In the village of 
                <textarea name="village" cols="10" rows="1" placeholder="enter village"></textarea>
                everybody knows that my name is 
                <textarea name="name" cols="10" rows="1" placeholder="enter name"></textarea>
                .

                My name is 
                <textarea name="name" id="" cols="10" rows="1" placeholder="enter name"></textarea>
                and I come from a village called
                <textarea name="village" cols="10" rows="1" placeholder="enter village"></textarea>
                  . In the village of 
                  <textarea name="village" cols="10" rows="1" placeholder="enter village"></textarea>
                  everybody knows that my name is 
                  <textarea name="name" cols="10" rows="1" placeholder="enter name"></textarea>
                  .
            </p>
        </form>
</body>
```

*/static/style.css*

```
textarea {
    margin: 0 5px;
    background-color: #eff0f1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can vertically center `inline-block` elements using `vertical-align: middle`.

You can set the width to 50% of the screen using `width: 50vw` and differentiate a smaller screen using the `@media screen and (max-width: 600px)`

You do not need to play with `flex` in this case, this will make things incredibly more complex. Meanwhile, you can consider `contenteditable` elements that will nicely align and expand the text naturally.

```css
[contenteditable] { color: blue; }
p { width: 50vw; margin: 0 auto; }
html, body { text-align: center; }
textarea { display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; }
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) { p { width: 100vw; } }
```

```html
<p>
    My name is <span contenteditable="true">enter name</span> and I come from a village
</p>

<p>
    My name is <textarea cols="10" rows="1" placeholder="enter name"></textarea> and I come from a village
</p>
```

Comment: This looks great! Is there a way to auto-grow a "textarea" just like "contenteditable" does? I need to wrap the <p> tags within a <form> so that is why I was using "textarea" and not "span".

Comment: You can enlarge the textarea using javascript but it will not wrap to a new line to follow the text. If you use unique `id="span_1"` on the span, you can collect their content with `document.getElementById("span_1").textContent` but I cannot tell if this would fit your need